# Static IP internet connection only connecting to router on Raspberry PI

Tags: wifi, internet, static-ip

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 here, using ssh and VNC to remotely access the internet whenever the RasPi detects WiFi, and this works with my static IP connecting to the router, but not to the Interwebs. I also tried android USB Internet tether and this also didn't work. When I connect to a TV using HDMI and stop using a static IP the internet works fine. I think my static ip configuration is blocking my Internet options.

TL;DR: I want to access WiFi with a static IP configured.

I have been trying this more than 2 weeks.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the contents of /etc/network/interfaces and the output of the fconfig command when configured for a static IP. You may also want to check the related links on the right as they may already include a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `ping 8.8.8.8` and `ping google.com` I think I know the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Really simple, if I've guessed right. I had this exact same problem when setting up a static IP with Wifi. You need to define your `dns-nameservers` if you are going to you a static IP address and not `dhcpd`. Simply add this to your `/etc/network/interfaces' file:

`dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8`

---

**Quick how-to, just in case:**

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`
then find the line below your main block that should look something like this:

```
address 172.16.0.16
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.0.1
```

and add `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8` right below it.

So it should look similar but not exactly like:

```
address 172.16.0.16
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 172.16.0.1
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Answer (score 0):

1. (undo whatever it is you did to set a static ip on your pi)
2. Log into your router's UI
3. Configure a static IP for your PI from there